# How to minimize database query in DjangoREST Serializer

Tags: python, django

`car/models.py`

```
class CarData(AbstractSoftModelController, AbstractDataType):
    ...
    license_plate = models.OneToOneField(LicensePlate,
                                         related_name='car_data',
                                         verbose_name=_('License plate'))
    ...
```

`license/models.py`

```
class LicensePlate(AbstractSoftModelController, AbstractDataType):
    hiragana_prefix = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Hiragana prefix'), null=True, blank=True
)
    vehicle_class_number = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Vehicle class number'), null=True, blank=True
)
    regional_code = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Regional code'), null=True, blank=True
)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class MailLogOrderCarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hiragana_prefix = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    vehicle_class_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    regional_code = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CarData
        fields = ('brand', 'model', 'license_plate')

    def get_hiragana_prefix(self, obj: CarData):
        return obj.license_plate.hiragana_prefix

    def get_vehicle_class_number(self, obj: CarData):
        return obj.license_plate.vehicle_class_number

    def get_regional_code(self, obj: CarData):
        return obj.license_plate.regional_code
```

**Question**
How do I optimize my serializer?
Hit database 3 times for single instance is not good. 
Suppose I query 500 cars. 
Then it will hit 1500 times which is considerable big performance issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

optimize serializer code

```
class MailLogOrderCarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hiragana_prefix = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='license_plate.hiragana_prefix')
    vehicle_class_number = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='license_plate.vehicle_class_number')
    regional_code = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='license_plate.regional_code')
```

not sure about db queries, but you can test it

Comment: Thank you. Save my lines :)

Comment: i hope not only lines

Comment: Hi. https://medium.com/@sarit.r/django-serializer-experiment-b5c440d50782 Unfortunately, it just the lines. Everything is exactly the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is adding the `.select_related('license_plate')` to the `queryset`.
Then when `view` call the `serializer` let it use customized query.